# Why need exclude=["node_modules"] when I just have include=["src"] in my tsconfig.json?

Tags: typescript, node-modules, tsconfig

I want to compile just the "src" folder. hence i do `include:["src"]`, and node_modules are found outside src only, then why do i need to exclude them like, `exclude: ["node_modules"]` as suggested by many sites?

e.g. they have also suggested that we include src and then exclude node_modules too - https://www.javatpoint.com/typescript-compilation-context

```
{  
    "compilerOptions": {  
        "module": "system",  
        "noImplicitAny": true,  
        "removeComments": true,  
        "preserveConstEnums": true,  
        "outFile": "../../built/local/tsc.js",  
        "sourceMap": true  
    },  
    "include": [  
        "src/**/*"  
    ],  
    "exclude": [  
        "node_modules",  
        "**/*.spec.ts"  
    ]  
}
```

I shouldn't have to write any exclude in my tsconfig.json, right?

Answer (score 4):

You understood it incorrectly. Values in the `include` array represent folders/files that are going to be included in the program. `exclude` then specifies what folders/files must be excluded from **the included folders/files**.

In other words, if you write `include: ['src']` and then `exclude: ['*.spec.ts']`, then you exclude every `*.spec.ts` file that was found **under** `src` folder.

You must exclude `node_modules`, even though the folder is outside the `src` folder. That's because those packages are **imported** (using `import`) inside the files (a.k.a modules) that are placed inside the included `src` folder. If you don't do that, TypeScript will check imported packages too and that's not something you want.

Since it is recommended to always exclude `node_modules`, TypeScript decided to add it as a default value. You can therefore omit the whole `exclude` specification if you only want to exclude `node_modules`.

Since you also want to exclude `*.spec.ts` files (not default), you need to specify it the way you did.

There are more folders that have been added to the array as default values `["node_modules", "bower_components", "jspm_packages"]`

You can read more about this topic [in the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exclude).

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't have to specify the `node_modules` in the `exclude` option because TypeScript automatically excludes it by default.

If `exclude` is disabled, TypeScript will include these directories as excluding.

```
- node_modules
- bower_components
- jspm_packages
- the files <outDir> option specifies
```

The `exclude` option is only used as filtering of the `include` option. So you can specify it only when using the `include` option.

Check out more detail with a sample example here.

https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/typescript-configuration-options-tsconfig-json-561d4a2ad4b